# Euler's path/circuit for PARTIALLY directed graph

Tags: graph-algorithm

We are building a bot for an Android game "One Touch Drawing master".Certain level requires us to find out Euler's path/circuit for a graph which has only some edges directed.

- Usual algorithm with modification in matrix accordingly won't work.(tested)
- Backtracking can be used, but with over 25 vertices and no. of edges between them, it is not practical.
- I went through some research papers, for eg. 
  [Covering partially Directed graphs with directed paths.](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0012365X06001968>)

I am stuck.Any solution about how to implement this algorithm?Will prefer practical solution rather than theoretical, need to code it right away.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: 25 vertices, and `it's not practical` ? maybe if you do by hand...

Comment: Nop, the backtracking complexity won't depend on no. of vertices. It will depend on No. of edges between them! which can be as high as 25C2.